# Improve error message when creating a new proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I was trying to create a new proposal and when I click the create button, I got sent back tot the first page with this error message.

```
"name and email, or your OpenID, are missing"
```

My profile looked OK to me, it had my name & email address and I'd clicked on the verification link in the email too.

What had happened was I was using an account that was recognising me from a cookie rather than a registered account.

The error didn't really make that clear.

Comment: Well... your openid was missing...

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now. Unregistered users with verified email addresses are now able to create proposals and post example questions.